# TIBCO instead of CCS

Tags: 2011

Is that possible to use TIBCO instead of CCS (SDL Tridion Cache Channel Service) ?

I come to know that we can use ActiveMQ from this article on the [trivident blog](http://blog.trivident.com/2012/09/tridion-and-jms-removing-another-spof).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have never tried it, but if it supports JMS, I can't see why it wouldn't work. The challenge you will have is TIBCO-related: which classes & jars do you need to use to allow Tridion to connect to it.

Once you figure that out, and configure it correctly in cd_storage_conf, the rest should be smooth sailing.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem .. We have the TIBCO setup done ... stuck with the Tridion storage config part...